# DropDownListFor doesn't work. Getting error: "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key *key*"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Model:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public string AuthorName { get; set; }

public int AuthorId { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(150)]
public string Title { get; set; }

public int? Pages { get; set; }
public int? Price { get; set; }

public virtual Authors Authors { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, ViewBag.AuthorId as SelectList)
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Books> authors;
    using (Model1 db = new Model1())
    {
        authors = db.Books.ToList();
        SelectList author = new SelectList(db.Authors, "Id", "FirstName", db.Authors.Select(model => model.Id));
        ViewBag.AuthorId = author;
    }
    return View(authors);




}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Checked the code, write everything correctly, but when you try to create a field with the name of the book, prices, and number of sheets-out this error :

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key *key*"

Do not know what it is, and how to fix it.

Tried to find a solution on the forums, but I still get the same result.

Moreover, if i use an EditorFor, and if i'm entering the Id of the created author - everything works. What am I doing wrong? What causes the error and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no propeprty `FirstName`, there is only `AuthorName` in your model

Comment: Also i don't understand which overload of `SelectList` you are using. Normally fourth parameter is the selected value, not sure how it is suppose to work with list you are passing in

Comment: @Andrei Could you show me how to properly use Dropdownlistfor with code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in your code that you have posted.

- ViewBag key and model property name shouldn't be same as it results in issues
- Make sure that `Authors` class has `FirstName` property
- `db.Authors.Select(model => model.Id)` is not needed at all in the constructor of `SelectList`

  Firstly, don't use the same key for `ViewBag` that you have property in your model. Change your view code to:

  ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, ViewBag.AuthorsList as SelectList)
  ```

and in controller action populate the `ViewBag.AuthorsList` like:

```
ViewBag.AuthorsList = new SelectList(db.Authors.Select(x =>
                                                       new 
                                                       {
                                                        Id = x.Id,
                                                        FirstName = x.FirstName
                                                       }).ToList(), 
                                      "Id", 
                                      "FirstName");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error. I just don't know what the problem is. You have any other ideas?

Comment: update the question with new code and exception with stack trace

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I did what you asked. Here's my screenshot with stack trace and code [link](https://dropmefiles.net/i/af3a36bea2242aa615c537c854b3b3cf/abe07f93fe4e8e6a3d9a22fe587ec9da)

Comment: And how you can see, it works with EditorFor commented below, but not with DropdownListFor. I don't know why.

Comment: I am away from machine, will see your updates when back

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure my Dropdown-code is correct, but i don't know what's the problem. I re-write it many times, but still getting the same exception.

Comment: @Dimitry49921 have you changed the `ViewBag.AuthorId` to `ViewBag.AuthorsList` in both controller and view ?

Comment: Thanks, i already have fix this error. I just replace SelectList code from Index to Create method. But anyway, thank you for helping me!